# Questions Regarding : Find the Sum of Last N nodes of the Linked List

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures, linked-list, nodes

I was solving this problem, Actually I did finish it. However, I still want to enhance my solution. Like is there another approach to solve this problem so the time complexity is reduced? my solution's time complextiy is O(n^2). Furthermore, I thought about a way to solve it recursively, but at the end I mixed the both; as I will traverse "Iteratively" to get `numOfNodes` and then traverse "Recursively" to count the last nodes. I did not implement it yet but I am confused about that solution and I do not know if it is right or not!

**please have a look at the code first ,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
The idea about it is to count to `numOfNodes` in the list, and then come over and traverse again but for each node I will reduce the `numOfNodes`. and when `numOfNodes == k`, then the sum is being calculated using a for loop.

Here is the code:

```
public int sum(Node head, int k){
      int sum = 0;
      int numOfNodes = 0;


      Node temp = new Node(0);
      temp = head;
      

      while(temp != null){
          numOfNodes++;
          temp = temp.next;
      }
      
      temp = head;
      
      while(temp != null){
          if(numOfNodes == k){
            for(int i = 0; i<k; i++){
                sum += temp.data;
                temp = temp.next;
            }
          }else{
            numOfNodes--;
            temp = temp.next;
          }
      }
      
      return sum;
    }
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Assuming it is a singly linked list, why not save the last k elements in an array? Or some FIFO collection with a limited size? Alternatively, you could add each element you come across, then subtract them once they step outside of the k range.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is optimistic about the number of nodes in the list. It will return 0 when the list has fewer than `k` nodes. I would think that in that case the sum of all nodes should be returned.

As to the rest of the algorithm: it is fine. It uses constant auxiliary memory and runs in linear time. It is not quadratic as you thought: although you loop a second time through the list, this just makes the number of iterations O(2n), which still is O(n).

You could also combine the two iterations into one, by keeping track of a second node reference that lags `k` nodes behind the leading node reference.

Here is how that would look:

```
public static int sum(Node head, int k){
    int total = 0;
    Node lag = head;
    Node lead = head;
    while (lead != null) {
        if (--k < 0) {
            total -= lag.data;
            lag = lag.next;
        }
        total += lead.data;
        lead = lead.next;
    }
    return total;
}
```

A recursive solution has as downside that it will need O(k) stack space.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Yeah I did not notice the correct time complexity I supposed that it is O(n^2) as there was a nested loop.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to keep space complexity constant O(1), your solution looks optimal. I am also assuming it is a singly linked list.

By the way, time complexity of your solution is not O(n^2). It is O(n). Your are doing one traversal to get total count. That is O(n).
You are doing another traversal to get the k nodes count. These are two independent traversals. So time complexity is n + n = 2n or O(n). There is no inner loop, so your solution works in O(n) time complexity.

Comment: Yeah it is a singly linked list. Thanks for the clarification, I did not notice that my solution has O(n) as I have just started to learn data structures and algorithms.

Answer (score 0):

Your iterative solution looks fine, although I would suggest simplifying your actual counting code to something like this:

```
Node temp = head;
for(int i=0; i<numOfNodes-k; i++) 
    temp = temp.next;

// temp now points to the first node to be counted

int sum = 0;
for(int i=0; i<k; i++) 
{
    sum += temp.data;
    temp = temp.next;
}
return sum;
```

The recursive solution you mentioned has the advantage of only having to traverse the list once, counting the top `k` nodes on the way back. Note that we have to use a reference value, (I'm using a simple one-element array), to hold the calculated limit above which we should count nodes.

```
static int sumr(Node node, int pos, int k, int[] lim)
{
    if(node == null)
    {
        // pos now holds the length of the list
        lim[0] = pos-k;
        return 0;
    }
    
    int sum = sumr(node.next, pos+1, k, lim);
    if(pos >= lim[0]) sum += node.data;
    return sum;
}
```

Called via:

```
int sum = sumr(head, 0, 3, new int[1]);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the suggestion and the recursive solution1

Answer (score -1):

It can be easily done in `O(N)` Time and `O(1)` Space complexity.
The idea is to iterate the list once and count the number of nodes in the list. Let the size of the list be `size`.
Now iterate the list once again and keep track of visited nodes. If `i` is in the desired range (last `k` nodes) then add the values of those nodes to the resultant `sum`.

```java
int i=1;
int sum = 0;
Node pointer = head;
while (pointer != null)
{
    if ((size-k) <= i)
    {
        sum += pointer.data;
    }
    i++;
    pointer = pointer.next;
}
```

Comment: Okay thanks a lot Mr. Shreyash. I was wondering about the O(1) solution, how it will be?

Comment: @omarahmed An O(1) solution is not possible as the size of the list can vary. `O(N)` is the best time complexity you can achieve here.